# problem understanding $a\times((b\cdot b)a-(b\cdot a)b)=-a\cdot ba\times b$

Tags: vector-analysis, cross-product

$a\times(b\times(a\times b))=a\times((b\cdot b)a-(b\cdot a)b)=-a\cdot ba\times b$
can anyone expand on how the final answer is derived?
I try to expand but ended up scratching my head.
the best I can do is this
$a\times(ab\cdot b - ab\cdot b)$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In $a\times((b\cdot b)a-(b\cdot a)b)$, the first term is zero because $a \times a = 0$. This leaves the second term. Note that $a\cdot b = b\cdot a$.

Comment: $a\times-(a\cdot b)b$ but how did it end up $-a\cdot ba \times b$?we could just exchange cross and dot operator, right?

Comment: sorry,forget what I said.Just found out about the cross product $(cu)\times v=u\times (cv)$